# Performance issue in Spring Boot Java app with SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, hibernate, mssql-jdbc

I am facing performance issues with a Spring Boot Java App which gets data from a SQL Server database. A simple query like:

```sql
SELECT a, b, SUM(c)
FROM table
WHERE date = '2023-02-01' AND year = 2023
GROUP BY a, b
```

is executed. The result of the query is 12 rows. When I execute this query in SSMS, the result is there immediately. If the query gets executed via the Spring Boot app in a browser window or with Postman, it takes randomly 3.5 to 10 seconds to get the result.

The table contains roughly 8 million rows and 14 columns:

- 1 PK INT column
- 1 DATE column
- 2 DECIMAL(12,2)
- 10 NVARCHAR(x)

The query in the Spring Boot app is written in Native SQL annotated with `@Query`. All my colleagues use ASP.NET as back-end, and they are taking the same SQL Server. Their performance is great. It looks like there are configuration issues.

What I have tried so far:

1. I added `sendParametersAsUnicode=false` to application.properties
2. I copied the entire table: instead of NVARCHAR(x) I took VARCHAR(x) for all string-related columns.
3. I tracked the execution time with Postman: >99% of execution time falls in the category transfer time.
4. I tried to annotate NVARCHAR(x) columns to annotate with @Nationalized
5. I read about this: https://vladmihalcea.com/sql-server-jdbc-sendstringparametersasunicode/ to understand the difference between NVARCHAR(x) and VARCHAR(x) in terms of Spring Boot and SQL Server.

Any ideas what might be the game changer to decrease execution time from multiple seconds to far less than a second?

Here is more code of my project:

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://10.191.144.180:1433;database=Spring;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=pw123456
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
```

[image: Postman]

Table Class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="Fact_Snapshots_Agg")
public class FSAGG {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;
    Date filedate;
    String jahr;
    String a;
    String b;
    String d;
    String e;
    String f;
    String g;
    String h;
    float c;
    float i;
    String j;
    String k;
}
plus constructors and getters and setters
```

Resource File:

```java
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.analytics_test.model.FSAGGTInterface;
import com.analytics_test.service.FSAGGService;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("/FSAGG")
public class FSAGGResource {
    private final FSAGGService fsaggService;
    
    @Autowired
    public FSAGGResource(FSAGGService fsaggService) { this.fsaggService = fsaggService; }
    
    @GetMapping("/Actuals/Total/{jahr}/gesamt")
    public List<FSAGGTInterface> getActualsTotalGesamt(@PathVariable("jahr") String jahr) { return fsaggService.getActualsTotalGesamt(jahr); }

}
```

Repository File:

```java
package com.analytics_test.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import com.analytics_test.model.FSAGG;
import com.analytics_test.model.FSAGGTInterface;

public interface FSAGGRepository extends JpaRepository<FSAGG, Long> {
    
    @Query(value = "a as a, b as b, SELECT SUM(c) as c "
            + "FROM FSAGG WHERE filedate = '2023-02-01' AND year = :year "
            + "GROUP BY a, b"
            )
    List<FSAGGTInterface> getActualsTotalGesamt(@Param("year") String year);
    
}
```

Service Class:

```java
package com.analytics_test.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.analytics_test.model.FSAGGTInterface;
import com.analytics_test.repository.FSAGGRepository;

@Component
@Service
public class FSAGGService {

    private final FSAGGRepository fsaggRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    public FSAGGService(FSAGGRepository fsaggRepository) { this.fsaggRepository = fsaggRepository; }
    
    public List<FSAGGTInterface> getStuff() { return fsaggRepository.getStuff(); }
    
    public List<FSAGGTInterface> getActualsTotalGesamt(String jahr) { return fsaggRepository.getActualsTotalGesamt(jahr); }

}
```

Comment: It all looks ok. To get a little more info ‘profile’ by putting code around fsaggService.getActualsTotalGesamt(jahr); to see it that is using most of the time.

Comment: Hi John, can you pls edit your comment? I dont get what you mean by that. The method getActualsTotalGesamt(jahr) wont be used anywhere else in my project.

Comment: Difficult to explain in comment. I have explained in “Answer”

Comment: @sebk, add the nativeQuery=true attribute to the Query annotation. Without it, it's not a native query even though it may look like it is.

Comment: Check out activity monitor or put a trace and compare query AND query plan between query from the app and just from SSMS

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the service method getActualsTotalGesamt to confirm that the slow query is the issue rather than something else in spring boot.

```
public List<FSAGGTInterface> getActualsTotalGesamt(String jahr) {
    Date start = new Date();
    List<FSAGGTInterface> retVal = fsaggRepository.getActualsTotalGesamt(jahr);
    System.out.println(“repo call duration ms: “ + ((new Date()).getTime() - start.getTime()));
    return retVal;
     }
```